# Firefox Password Manager - Keeps asking for master password at startup

Tags: firefox, passwords

I use Firefox 79.0 for Windows 10 (64-bit) and have set up a master password. The problem is that on every start up Firefox keeps asking me for the password, eventhough my starting page doesn't have any password required. I want Firefox to behave in a way that it only asks for a password, if I visit a website that requires a password, that I stored into my manager.

Some Support pages imply ([Firefox keeps asking me for Primary Password](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-keeps-asking-me-primary-password?redirectslug=firefox-keeps-asking-me-master-password&redirectlocale=en-US)) just a reset - didn't work for me. [Others](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1039575) suggest that the problem lies with the fact that I'm using sync and suggest to turn it only on when necessary. But I don't want to turn off sync.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try: (1) [run Firefox in safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) to see if it behaves better in this mode, (2) uninstall and reinstall Firefox (make a backup copy of the profile folder and especially export bookmarks).

Comment: Have you tried these ?

Comment: @harrymc not yet, ill try it later

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunetaly it behaves the same way

Comment: Ah, you're back. Which password is being asked?

Comment: @harrymc the master password. I think its very inconventient if it gets asked every time I reopen the browser (sometimes even multiple times per session). So I want the password only to be asked, if I enter a website that needs a password

Comment: But that's exactly what the Primary Password (aka Master Password) was [designed](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-primary-password-protect-stored-logins-and-pas?redirectslug=use-master-password-protect-stored-logins&redirectlocale=en-US) to do: "After you have defined and set your primary password, you will be prompted to enter it once for each Firefox session". Maybe you need another solution. Why do you need this password?

Comment: @harrymc I get it, but still there must be a solution that reduces the effort to retyping the same password. I use it for safety.

Comment: You may use a macro product such as AutoHotkey to write out this password when a hotkey is pressed. I can help with that.

Comment: @harrymc Hehe I guess. i ll check all the firefox settings first. I just think a password manager makes sense to protect yourself in case your laptop gets stolen. since win 10 does not offer any encryption for the non prof version, i at least dont want a thief immedeatly to know all my passwords that i store in firefox...

Comment: You may encrypt the entire Firefox folder, so you will only need to unlock it once each boot. The minus is that a glitch can lose you the whole thing.

Comment: @harrymc i like that idea... since i use sync i dont worry too much about it :)

Comment: You could always use a different password manager. [BitWarden](https://bitwarden.com/), for instance, is a free, open-source password manager with extensions on Chrome and Firefox, and apps on Android and iOS. Not affiliated, just like the product. You can set the master password timeout to a couple different options, and you only need to enter it when you need a password.

Comment: @jeremysprofile Thanks, yeah I thought about it but never tried. I ll check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Primary Password (aka Master Password) was
[designed](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-primary-password-protect-stored-logins-and-pas?redirectslug=use-master-password-protect-stored-logins&redirectlocale=en-US)
to do exactly that:

> After you have defined and set your primary password, you will be prompted to enter it once for each Firefox session

Alternatively, you may encrypt the Firefox profile folder instead of using
a Primary Password.
This way you will only need to unlock it once per boot.

Here are two alternatives:

- Windows EFS : See the article
  [How to Encrypt Files and Folders with Encrypting File System (EFS) in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/77130-encrypt-files-folders-efs-windows-10-a.html)
- The free [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html)

Comment: thought about writing my own encrypting code. But i ll check out your links soon and accept your answer.

Comment: Never implement encryption by your own, except you know exactly what you are doing.